# fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, continuous-integration, github-actions, nrwl-nx, git-fetch

I'm using [NX](https://nx.dev/) in my CI with [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) and I checkout the repository using [actions/checkout@v4](https://github.com/actions/checkout).

When I try to use `nx affected:...`, for example `nx affected:lint` or `nx affected:test` it fails with the following error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the
> working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [...] -- [...]'

The problem is that the `main` branch is not available. I tried to fix this problem using `fetch-depth: 0` as suggested by the [checkout action's documentation](https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#usage), but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following command before your `:affected` command to ensure your CI environment has an unambiguous main available in your branch.

`git rev-parse --verify main || git remote set-branches origin main && git fetch --depth 1 origin main && git branch main origin/main`

What this does is

- verifies if the `main` branch is unambiguous (see [git rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---verify))
- otherwise execute the following:

  1. set list of branches tracked by remote (see [git set-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-branchesem))
  2. re-fetch the last commit from main (to be able to compare with affected)
  3. set remote tracking for local `main` to match `origin/main`

This would, however, fail if you run the command while on `main` already, so you should only execute it in a branch.

Something like this in your `yml` should do the trick:

```yaml
if: github.ref != 'refs/heads/main'
run: git rev-parse --verify main || git remote set-branches origin main && git fetch --depth 1 origin main && git branch main origin/main
```